# so deep as that into his feelings?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He paused; then went on: I don't know that the commanding officer delved **so deep as that into his feelings.** But he did suffer from them—a sort of disenchanted sadness. It is possible, even, that he suspected himself of folly. Man is various. But he had no time for much introspection, because from the southwest a wall of fog had advanced upon his ship. Great convolutions of vapours flew over, swirling about masts and funnel, which looked as if they were beginning to melt. Then they vanished.

This is a paragraph excerpted from a short story by Joseph Conrad: Tha Tale. 
At first glimpse, I thought it is a plain "so adjective as" comparison sentence. I, however, got lost where "that" popped up.

1) I cannot understand why there is "that" right after "as", and what its grammatical function is.

2) I wonder what this sentence means. Does this mean that the narrator(I) doesn't know that the commanding officer delved so deep into something as the commanding officer delved deep into his feelings?

Answer (score 2):

"That" refers back to something previously mentioned before your quotation begins.

The quote comes from *The Tale* by Joseph Conrad. Prior to your quotation, it speaks of "*the murderous stealthiness of methods and the atrocious
callousness of complicities that seemed to taint the very source of
men's deep emotions and noblest activities; to corrupt their
imagination which builds up the final conceptions of life and death.*"

So, by saying "I don't know that the commanding officer delved so deep as *that* into his feelings", he is saying that he does not think the officer delved as deep so as to consider the "deep emotions and noblest activities" that they had just spoken of.

Comment: In *most* contexts, ***as that*** probably wouldn't be included. The contextually-relevant "level of depth" is already referred back to by ***so***, making it redundant. I think the net effect of including it is to provide *emphasis* (speaker implies "that" level is ***very** deep*). Or maybe it just makes it "easier" to convey that emphasis by placing heavy stress on the word ***that*** - which of course can equally be done by stressing ***so** deep[ly]* while discarding ***as that***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say "*as* deep *as* that", but "so deep" sounds like an Americanism so I'm ignoring that. It is a quotation from a published work, so I've just focused on the explanation rather than the grammar.

Comment: I don't see much difference between [BrE "would not go **so / as** far"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+not+go+so+far%2Cwould+not+go+as+far&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20not%20go%20so%20far%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20not%20go%20as%20far%3B%2Cc0) and [the AmE equivalent.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+not+go+so+far%2Cwould+not+go+as+far&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20not%20go%20so%20far%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20not%20go%20as%20far%3B%2Cc0)